# jQuery Cookie doesn't work

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a problem, my jQuery cookie doesn't work.

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $.cookie("isHidden", "true", {
            expires: 1
        });
        $(".notice").hide();
        return false;
    });

    var hidden = $.cookie("isHidden");

    if (hidden === null) {
        $('.notice').show();
    }
});
```

And when I remove the cookie, the script works fine!
Also checked with jsfiddle.net - and it's says it works fine.

Comment: The cookie plugin is widely used and works just fine, it's something you're doing that is the issue, but witn no explanation as to what the problem is, other than that it's fine in jsFiddle, it's really hard to help you out with this ?

Comment: Maybe share the jsfiddle?

Comment: The problem is that, when i click on ".close" the div hides, but when i reload the page, It's still there.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be, you're not hiding the div, you're showing it. Try doing `$('.notice').toggle( $.cookie("isHidden") );` instead